# Match a binary string which contains a sub set that should not be all zeros

Tags: regex

As the title states, I am trying to make a regular expression that, given arbitrary positions, matches a binary string which contains a sub set that should not be all zeros( or at least one 1), for example:

```
binary:   100101
          -------
position: 123456
```

when arbitrary position is `123`, then matching return `true`, because the first one is 1; 
when arbitrary position is `235`, then matching return `false`, because none of them is 1; 
when arbitrary position is `236`, then matching return `true`, because the last one is 1;

I know some regular expression, but I really don't know how to approach this one. any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to use regexes at all? Instead of building a custom regex for a given set of positions, you could just iterate over the set of positions and announce a match as soon as you find a 1 in the current position (if you don't find a 1 at all, no match is found).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your string can consist only of 1s and 0s, invert the test. Construct a regex that matches zero in each arbitrary position and then test that it doesn't match.

For each position, store a '0' at that index. Otherwise, a '.' to allow any character.

For example:

```
235 -> .00.0.
```

Then test for no match:

```
.00.0. matches '100101'
```

so 235 would be `false`.

Comment: a smart idea, really appreciate it. :)